# return a list view in visual webpart

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint-online, visual-web-part

In have the following code which returns a list and binds it to my repeater.

```
Dim Partnership As SPList = web.Lists("PartnersMedia")
rptPartnership.DataSource = Partnership.Items.GetDataTable()
rptPartnership.DataBind()
```

This is returning all the items in the list, what I want is a particular item so I have created a view which displays the 1 item.  Can i access the view in a similar way to above?

TIA.

S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build a CAML query using [SPQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spquery.aspx)

Then you can use something like the following

```
Dim Partnership As SPList = web.Lists("PartnersMedia") 
Dim query As New SPQuery()
query.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Status'/><Value Type='Text'>Completed</Value></Eq></Where>"
rptPartnership.DataSource = Partnership.GetItems(query).GetDataTable() 
rptPartnership.DataBind()
```

Comment: thanks Per, get an error on build now...Error 2 'GetItems' is not a member of 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItemCollection'

Comment: Sorry sample changed it's directly on the list

Comment: Out of interest can I do an "Order by" on that CAML query?

Comment: Yes you can prefix `<Where>...` with `<OrderBy>
  <FieldRef Name="Field1" />
  <FieldRef Name="Field2" Ascending="FALSE"/>
</OrderBy>`

Comment: Hmm can I just check something with you Per?  My solution is going up on SharePoint online is SPQuery() allowed for SP online?

Comment: Yes, it's the way to query SharePoint list also used by views. If that wasn't supported you'd have no way of getting data from SharePoint list as merely accesing SPList.Items will cause throttling if there is many items in the list.